# Autoload PHP Classes using Composer

Tags: php, interface, composer-php

I am trying for the first time to autoload PHP Classes using Composer.

I have this dir structure:

```
-app
  -controllers
  -models
    -MySql.php
    -interfaces
      -IDatabase.php
```

My problem is that I am not able to implement the `IDatabase interface` in my `MySql` class. It gives me: `Fatal error: Interface 'App\Models\I\IDatabase' not found`.

**composer.json**

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  }
}
```

**IDatabase.php**

```
namespace App\Models\I;

interface IDatabase
{

  public function connect();
  public function execute($query,$param);
}
```

**Mysql.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\I\IDatabase;

class MySql implements IDatabase
{
...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Casing is important!  `app` vs `App`, etc.  or `app\models\interfaces\IDatabase`  It's probably mainly this one `I` vs `interfaces` but Casing will get you on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like

```
App\Models\I\IDatabase
```

Should be

```
App\Models\Interfaces\IDatabase
```

You can't abbreviate the directory name.

Also as I said in the comments

> Casing is important! app vs App, etc. or app\models\interfaces\IDatabase It's probably mainly this one I vs interfaces but Casing will get you on Linux.

So you can either change the directories to be uppercase, or you can change the namespace to be lower cased (but they should be the same).

On windows this may work with the case issues, because windows filesystem is case insensitive. But as soon as you put that on Linux which is case sensitive, well it's not gonna work out to good.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces should follow the exact directory structure, and are case sensitive.

If your Interface is in the directory `app\models\interfaces`, the namespace should be `App\models\interfaces`. `App` in your case can be with capital `A` because you explicitly mapped it in the `composer.json`.

So you can either rename the folders or fix the namespace.

Also, you cannot give custom name to the namespaces (i.e. `I` in `App\Models\I`). As I stated before, the namespace must follow the directory structure, unless you create a specific mapping in the composer.json